# CockroachDB SERIAL field not working with JPA IDENTITY Strategy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cockroachdb

I'm migrating an app to use CockroachDB and we are using the GeneratedValue mapping in Java with SERIAL type columns to manage primary keys.

```
id                   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY -- SQL

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) -- Java JPA
```

We are getting the following error

> ERROR: currval(): relation "scm_supply_centers_id_seq" does not exist

We dug a little and found out that it's because of PostgreSQL Dialect trying to get the last id inserted in as you can see in this link
[PostgreSQL81IdentityColumnSupport](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/69000ddc165ca0aba13ac950b2637974e018c4fb/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/dialect/identity/PostgreSQL81IdentityColumnSupport.java#L22)

How can I find a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The `SERIAL` type is not backed by a sequence in CockroachDB. In order to use a `SEQUENCE` you need to explicitly create it and use the `nextval()` function as the `DEFAULT` value for the column. For example,

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customer_seq;

CREATE TABLE customer_list (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('customer_seq'),
    customer string,
    address string
);
```

Note that there are performance implications to using `SEQUENCE` vs `SERIAL` due to the additional synchronization and communication requirements. See https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/create-sequence.html for more details.

The above doesn't exactly answer your question, though. I don't know how you would use an explicit sequence from Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks! That’s an alternative. I fixed it by implementing a custom Hibernate Dialect to allow returning the ID in the insert clause.